# Is it possible to use both absolute panel and sliderInput in same ui.R (shiny)?

Tags: r, slider, shiny

This is my `ui.R`. This is an example provided in Shiny tutorial. I just edited it.

```
library(shiny)
library(markdown)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot"),
absolutePanel(
  bottom = 0, left=420,  width = 800,
    draggable = TRUE,
    wellPanel(
em("This panel can be moved")      

      )
)    

  ))
))
```

and my `server. R`

```
library(shiny)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  # Expression that generates a histogram. The expression is
  # wrapped in a call to renderPlot to indicate that:
  #
  #  1) It is "reactive" and therefore should be automatically
  #     re-executed when inputs change
  #  2) Its output type is a plot
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2]  # Old Faithful Geyser data
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
})**
```

In this case, sliderInput is not working. If i remove absolute panel, sliderInput is ok. What may be the problem? 
 Many thanks

Comment: you have a typo in an argument to absolutePanel: draggaInputble = TRUE,

Comment: @Fadeaway, I am very sorry, I made mistake while copying and pasting here. Now i edited it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue: setting `draggable = FALSE` in the `absolutePanel` call seems to fix the problem with the slider, but clearly they should be able to co-exist. It also works if you move the slider into your `absolutePanel`, so I believe it is likely that the current problem is simply a bug to be fixed. You might consider changing the title of your question to reflect that, or reporting it as a bug on the github site: [https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues)

Answer (score 2):

The absolutePanel uses the jqueryui javascript library. It has its own slider. This results in a conflict with sliderInput which uses jslider library. You can see this as follows:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(
  list(ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("bins",
                    "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1,
                    max = 50,
                    value = 30)
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("distPlot")
        , tags$head(tags$script(src = "shared/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"))

      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      x    <- faithful[, 2]  # Old Faithful Geyser data
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
  }
  )
)
```

EDIT: This has been fixed in the latest dev version of shiny. The slider component has been removed from the jqueryui inc.  https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/commit/7e12a281f51e047336ba2c501fcac43af5253225